# Hibernation mode in Linux

Tags: linux

I am using 3.5.0-rc1-smp+ kernel. And when I close the cover of the laptop on Windows 7 the computer comes into hibernation mode with HDD and fans off. The machine stays cool.

But in Linux the drive is still periodically clicking and the fans are slowly moving. The laptop stays hot.

How can I make it work like in Windows?

Comment: Which distribution are you using? Do you use a desktop environment? If yes, which one? We need a little more information than just the kernel version.

Comment: I use Slackware 13.37 with KDE 4.5.5

Answer (score 0):

If you use the GNOME desktop environment, you can use `gsettings`. There are two cases to distinguish and can be set seperately: if the laptop is running on AC or on battery.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action hibernate
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action hibernate
```